# Is the system memory-less?

Tags: signals, signal-processing

I got a Question on digital signal processing.
Is

```
h(n)= (2 n+5)u(n)
```

memory-less? I think that the because of `u(n)`, the system is memory-less. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: No, assuming the provided `h(n)` represents the usual system impulse response.

A memoryless system is [characterized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_analysis#Characterization_of_systems) with outputs that do not depend on past inputs (and commonly also do not depend on future input). In terms of the impulse response it means that the response `h(n)` at a time `n>0` should not depend on the input at time 0, namely the impulse itself. In other words you should have `h(n) = 0` for `n>0` (but `h(n)` can be non-zero at time `n=0`).

In your case, the output starts to grow after the impulse is applied, so those outputs at time `n>0` clearly depend on the then past impulse input. So, the system is not memoryless.

*P.S.:* the presence of `u(n)` indicates that the system's output does not depends on future inputs (e.g. the output at time `-1` does not depend on the then future impulse which the system has not seen).

Comment: @EsraaEid Glad it help. Note that it is always appreciated to accept an answer (by clicking on the tick mark below the votes) if it answered your question. As a side benefit, you also get a little bit of reputation from this.