# Is the system memory or memoryless?

Tags: signals, signal-processing

I got this question in digital signal processing: Is the system

```
y(n) = 2*x(n)u(n-1)
```

memory-less?

my answer was memory-less because of `u(n-1)`. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29294662/2994596):

> A memoryless system is [characterized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_analysis#Characterization_of_systems) with outputs that do not depend on past inputs (and commonly also do not depend on future inputs).

So, provided `x(n)` represents your input (and `y(n)` represents your output), then the system is indeed memoryless. However it is because any current sample `y(n)` at time `n` only depends on the current input `x(n)` at that time, rather than because of the presence of the `u(n-1)` term.

If on the other hand, `x(n)` is an unspecified function of the input sequence (which could be for example `x(n) = w(n)-w(n-1)` where `w(n)` is the real input sequence), then the system may or may not be memoryless depending on the definition of the `x(n)` function.